# turn off debug mode in Chrome developer tools

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, authentication

I'm a mid level website designer and manager for clients sites and I know just enough HTML/CSS to be dangerous. I use the Chrome developer tools to see where I can make CSS changes primarily. 
     Now for some reason, the debugging tool pauses no matter what I do. I've turned off the pause button, but it makes no difference. Has anyone else had this issue? Do I have a virus or something?
     I'm trying to make CSS changes to a Wordpress login page and I can't even get it to react to my changes so I can see what I like. 
     Thanks in advance for any help. Here is my ugly login page that I need to fix:
http://tracoutdoor.com/wp-login.php

Comment: At what point does the debugger pause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your debugger may be set to break on exceptions automatically.  If you open the dev tools and click the **Sources** tab and look at the right hand menu, ensure both the Breakpoints and Exceptions icons are greyed out (not blue) like below:

[image: Example screenshot]

Also ensure there are no breakpoints set in the Breakpoints section.

Comment: That's what it was. Even though I had it turned off, some of the breakpoints were still selected. I may have inadvertently set them...who knows. I never use that level of debugging. I only ever use Elements. That's why it threw me. Anyway, I went in and deselected all those check boxes and I'm good to go. Thanks for following up! Two heads are definitely better than one.